# Aumentar a velocidade da transferência ao pressionar o mouse (hold)?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando utilizar os botões para transferir de um usuário para o outro, mas gostaria de ao clicar e pressionar o mouse aumentar a velocidade, já quando clicar apenas, passar os valores de um a um.

Alguém pode me ajudar?. Já comecei a fazer algumas tentativas com a função addSpeed(), no JS, mas ainda sem sucesso.

O código abaixo é apenas para podermos reproduzir aqui, o código completo com css não coube no Snippet, caso queiram visualizar segue [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xamta0b/1/).

```js
//var minValue = 10; //10MB


function formatNumberComma (num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
}

function formatNumber(num){
   num = num/1000;

  if(num == parseInt(num)){
    return formatNumberComma(parseInt(num));
  }

  return formatNumberComma(num.toFixed(2));
}

//server side values
var initialValuesUserbar = {
  'minValue': 10, //min value
  'usersInfo': [
    //left
    {
      name: 'Marianna',
      value: 50000,
      avulso: 4000,
      bloqueado: true
    },
    //right
    {
      name: 'Ludmilla',
      value: 50000,  //3000
      avulso: 0,
      bloqueado: false
    }
  ]
}

var currentValuesUserbar = [];


var setInitialBarValues = function(values){
  //console.log(values)
  var usersInfo = values.usersInfo;
  var left = usersInfo[0];
  var right = usersInfo[1];

  currentValuesUserbar.push(left.value)//[0]
  currentValuesUserbar.push(right.value)//[1]

  //$('.warn-message-info.ator-desabilitado').hide();
  $('.blocknumber-left').hide();
  $('.blocknumber-right').hide();

  if(left.bloqueado) $('.blocknumber-left').show();
  if(right.bloqueado) $('.blocknumber-right').show();

  //left
  $('.left-name').text(left.name)
  $('.left-value').text(formatNumber(left.value));

  // if(left.avulso) {
  //   $('.left-avulso-value').text("+" + formatNumber(left.avulso) +" GB avulso")
  // }

  $('.right-name').text(right.name)
  $('.right-value').text(formatNumber(right.value))

  // if(right.avulso){
  //   $('.right-avulso-value').text("+" + formatNumber(right.avulso) +" GB avulso")
  // }
}

function addSpeed(){
  hold_trigger.mousedown(function() {
          
    userEventClickId = setTimeout(funcao_teste, hold_time);
  }).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
      clearTimeout(userEventClickId);
      // voltar ao tempo normal aqui
  });

  function funcao_teste() {
    // acelerar o tempo aqui
  }
};

function clearErrorAdd(){
  $('.left-container-avulso').removeClass('nactive')
  $('.right-container-avulso').removeClass('nactive')
  $('.warn-message-info.ator-desabilitado').removeClass('active');
  $('.warn-message-info.ator-desabilitado').addClass('nactive');
  $('.panel-heading__blockNumber').removeClass('dipnone');

}

function showWarningMessage(className){
  $(className).addClass('nactive')
  $('.warn-message-info.ator-desabilitado').removeClass('nactive');
  $('.warn-message-info.ator-desabilitado').addClass('active');
  $('.warn-message-info.ator-desabilitado .phone').text(initialValuesUserbar.usersInfo[0].phone);
  $('.panel-heading__blockNumber').addClass('dipnone');
}

function incrementRight(hasAnimation){
  
  if(currentValuesUserbar[0] > initialValuesUserbar.minValue){
    currentValuesUserbar[0] -= 10;
    currentValuesUserbar[1] += 10;
    $('.left-value').text(formatNumber(currentValuesUserbar[0]))
    $('.right-value').text(formatNumber(currentValuesUserbar[1]))

    clearErrorAdd();

    $('.right-container-avulso').addClass('animate')

    if(hasAnimation){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.right-container-avulso').removeClass('animate')
      }, 300)
    }
  } else {
    $('.right-container-avulso').removeClass('animate')
    showWarningMessage('.left-container-avulso')
    return true;
  }
  
}


function incrementLeft(hasAnimation){
  
  if(currentValuesUserbar[1] > initialValuesUserbar.minValue){
    currentValuesUserbar[1] -= 10;
    currentValuesUserbar[0] += 10;
    $('.left-value').text(formatNumber(currentValuesUserbar[0]))
    $('.right-value').text(formatNumber(currentValuesUserbar[1]))

    clearErrorAdd();

    $('.left-container-avulso').addClass('animate')

    if(hasAnimation){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.left-container-avulso').removeClass('animate')
      }, 300)
    }
  } else {
    $('.left-container-avulso').removeClass('animate')
    showWarningMessage('.right-container-avulso')
    return true;
  }
}

//document ready
window.onload = function(){


function menu_toggle() {
  $('.spinner').addClass('active');
}
  
  var userEventClickId = 0;
  var incrementTimeInterval = 200;

  var hold_time = 1000; // tempo para começar a acelerar
  hold_trigger = $('.btn-left'); 

  var time = 150;

  $('.btn-right').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    incrementRight(true);
  })
  .on('mousedown', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
    
        userEventClickId = setInterval(function(){
          if(incrementRight()) {
            clearInterval(userEventClickId);
            return;
          }
        }, time); //150
  }).on('mouseleave', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();

      clearInterval(userEventClickId);
      $('.right-container-avulso').removeClass('animate')
  });

  $('.btn-left').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    incrementLeft(true);
  })
  .on('mousedown', function(event) {  
      event.preventDefault();
      userEventClickId = setInterval(function(){
        if(incrementLeft()) {
          clearInterval(userEventClickId);
          return;
        }
      }, time); //150
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();

      clearInterval(userEventClickId);

      $('.left-container-avulso').removeClass('animate')
  });
  //set initial
  setInitialBarValues(initialValuesUserbar);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="./transferencia.js"></script>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="home-produto" class="main pull-left">



              <!-- style_minhaoi_nav_produto :: INICIO -->
            <div id="divContent">
              <!-- begin: style_minhaoi_container_plano -->
              <div id="box-internet">
                      <div class="panel panel-default row box-produto">
                          <div class="panel-body">



                      <section class="section__title">
                        <p class="title-cingapura">Transferência de valores</p>
                      </section>




                                  <section class="section__transferencia--selecionados">
                        <div class="panel panel-default text-align--center col-xs-5 left-container-avulso">
                         <div class="panel-heading">
                            <p class="panel-heading__itemName left-name"></p>
                            <span class="panel-heading__itemNumber cor__second left-phone"></span>
                         </div>
                         <div class="panel-body">
                            <p class="panel-heading__itemQty">
                              <span class="left-value"></span>
                              <span class="panel-heading__itemQty--lower"> GB</span>
                            </p>

                         </div>
                       </div>
                       <ul class="transferencia-arrows col-xs-1">
                         <li><a href="#" class="btn-right">
                         <button class="material-icons arrow-icon">
                         >
                         </button>
                         </a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="btn-left"><button class="material-icons arrow-icon"><</button></a></li>
                       </ul>
                        <div class="panel panel-default text-align--center col-xs-5 right-container-avulso">
                         <div class="panel-heading">
                            <p class="panel-heading__itemName right-name"></p>
                            <span class="panel-heading__itemNumber cor__second right-phone"></span>
                         </div>

                         <div class="panel-body">
                             <p class="panel-heading__itemQty">
                               <span class="right-value"></span>
                               <span class="panel-heading__itemQty--lower"> GB</span>
                             </p>

                          </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>

                                  </section>



                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <!-- end: div_box_produto -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- end: div_id_produto -->
                  <!-- end: style_minhaoi_container_plano -->

                  </div>
                  <!-- end: div_content -->
          </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

de uma olhada neste exemplo, talvez lhe esclareça em como pode fazer essa funcionalidade.

```js
const TICK = 300; // milliseconds

var initialSpeed = 1;
var maxSpeed = 100;

var initialStorage = 200;

var speedValue = document.createTextNode(initialSpeed);

var currentStorageValue = document.createTextNode(initialStorage);
var currentBackpackValue = document.createTextNode(0);

document.querySelector('#speed').appendChild(speedValue);
document.querySelector('#storage').appendChild(currentStorageValue);
document.querySelector('#backpack').appendChild(currentBackpackValue);

/*
  Transfere do storage p/ backpack.
  Utiliza um Timeout para chamar a função novamente após
  o tempo estipulado. (Evita o problema que ocorre com o Interval
  que faz com que a animação pare quando o tempo muda)
*/
function transferToBackpack() {
  if (currentStorageValue.data <= 0) {
    console.log("Storage is empty..");
  } else {
    currentStorageValue.data--;
    currentBackpackValue.data++;
    setTimeout(transferToBackpack, (TICK / (speedValue.data / 5)));
  }
}

// Interval q executa enquanto user pressiona o mouse
var speedUpInterval;

// Interval q executa após user liberar o mouse
var speedDownInterval;
var container = document.querySelector('#press');
container.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  console.log('pressing...');
  if(speedDownInterval) clearInterval(speedDownInterval);
  speedUpInterval = setInterval(function() {
   if(speedValue.data < maxSpeed) {
     speedValue.data++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(speedUpInterval);
    }
  }, TICK);
});

container.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  console.log('releasing...');
  if(speedUpInterval) clearInterval(speedUpInterval);
  speedDownInterval = setInterval(function() {
   if(speedValue.data > 1) {
     speedValue.data--;
    } else {
      clearInterval(speedDownInterval)
    }
  }, TICK);
});

transferToBackpack();
```

```css
#press {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
  <p>Transfer Speed: <span id="speed"></span></p>
  <p>Storage: <span id="storage"></span></p>
  <p>Backpack: <span id="backpack"></span></p>
  
  <div id="press">
    <span>Press me!</span>
  </div>
```